# How come the ground under Aragorn's army did not collapse after the ring is destroyed?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-return-of-the-king

In Battle of the Morannon, when the ring is destroyed in Mount doom, the Dark Tower collapses. Then, The Eye of Sauron implodes and creates a shock wave which causes an earthquake that shatters the ground and ground starts to collapse.

So in this scene, How come the ground did not collapse under Aragorn's army and the fellowship? Is it because of the presence of Gandalf? or does he use a special spell?

Can it be even related with Eru (Ilúvatar) ?

You can see the scene in this video as well: (at 2m55s)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyzE9thQIPo&t=2m55s

Comment: One theory is that the ground collapsed to the borders of Mordor and no further. The fellowship was outside of the gates of Mordor and that's why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIR this didn’t happen in the book.

On *Science Fiction & Fantasy SE*, there is a [similar question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/32402/10622), and [Jim Green](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/9309/jim-green) [answered](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/32412/10622):

> The ground collapsing under the orcs and not the humans was a visual effect added by Peter Jackson and his crew.

So if it’s true that this wasn’t mentiond in any of Tolkien’s works, there can be no canonical answer whether this would have to do with Eru, Gandalf, a spell or something else.

Comment: Well yes, but that doesn't really answer the question (which unfortunately I don't think is really answerable).

Comment: I think this answers it. If it wasn't in the book then it didn't happen in the story so the answer is it didn't collapse because Peter Jackson didn't want it to.

Comment: How is that scene explained in the book?

Comment: @DustinDavis Of course it *did* happen in the story, we've clearly seen it happen. But I agree that *Peter Jackson*'s preference is the most likely reason (which isn't really what this answer is saying, though).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: Not saying, but implying. If it’s true that this is not mentioned in the books or in other works of Tolkien, then this was made up by Peter Jackson. And then there *can* be no answer if this has to do with Eru or Gandalf or a spell. (There may be an answer why Jackson did it or what he thought about it, but this would be a different question, I guess.)

Comment: @unor Still the question wasn't who's idea it was to create that or if it was in the books, but what the reason for this incident was. If this is not answerable (which might be the case), then that's bad luck. But this doesn't really make this answer any more complete (yet a statement about the unlikeliness of a "proper" reason might already help a lot). But I also agree that the information from the answer might have at least some relevance, which for now keeps me from downvoting it.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: I’m not sure if I understand you correctly; I edited the answer, would you now say that this is more complete?